# Attaching Click Event to DIV Using jQuery Library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am aware I can use the click function to attach an event to the DIV element but for some reason it is not working for me. Here is how I am creating the DIV element.

```
function createColorSwatchDiv(color) {

    var colorSwatchDiv = $("<div>");

    var image = $("<img>");
    image.attr("src",color.imageURL);

    var label = $("<label>");
    label.text(color.title);

    colorSwatchDiv.append(image);

    return colorSwatchDiv;

}
```

Then I try to attach the click event like the following:

```
   // run a loop and build the grid layout
    for(index = 0; index < colors.length; index++) {

        var colorSwatchDiv = createColorSwatchDiv(colors[index]);

        // attach the event
        colorSwatchDiv.click(function(){

                alert('hello world');

        });

        colorsSection.append(colorSwatchDiv);

    }

    // add to the dom
    $("#color .imageChartOption").after(colorsSection);
```

But it does not work and no click event is been attached.

Comment: `$("<div'>");` is invalid syntax

Comment: Works fine for me if I append it to the DOM: http://jsfiddle.net/o79hrLse/

Comment: You have a typo :)...

Comment: Strange. It must be treated as a custom DOM element.

Comment: I have edited the original question and removed the quotes. But still I am not able to handle the click event.

Comment: I have updated the code to include the colorSection container in which all the colorsSwatches are added. Still I am not able to invoke the event.

Answer (score 1):

following is the code

```
 var $newdiv1 = $("<div id='object1' onClick=Test()>Hello</div>");

 $("body").append($newdiv1);


function Test()
{
    alert("Clicked");
}
```

OR

```
  $newdiv1.on('click',function(){alert("hello");});
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have created the div in a jQuery wrapper you don't need to wrap it again here `$(colorSwatchDiv).click(...`. Also, are you sure that the `colorSwatchDiv` variable is referencing the dom element and not the in memory element? Can you apply a class or anything to the elm in the dom?